# $lookup with nested documents

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collections that I need to join/lookup.
"Groups"
"Users"
"LinkedTags"
"Photos"

I'm getting all groups from collection groups.

```
group {
    id: 1,
    start: 10.12,
    linkedUsers : [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Then I need to lookup/join from users

```
user {
    id: 1,
    name: ""
}
```

Then from linkedTags

```
tag {
    userId: 1,
    rounds: 3,
    time: 180
}
```

Then from "photos"

```
photo {
    userId: 1,
    location: ""
}
```

So I need this to be:

```
Group {
    id: 1,
    start: 10.12,
    linkedUsers: [1,2,3,4],
    users: [
        1:{
            id: 1,
            name: "",
            rounds: 3,
            time: 180,
            photos: [
                1: {
                    id: 1,
                    location: ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I have tried so far. I think I need to do it in stages, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

```
  db('groups').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'linkedUsers',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'users'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$users"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'photos',
        localField: 'linkedUsers',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'photos'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$photos"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'linkedTags',
        localField: 'linkedUsers',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'tags'
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        id: "$id",
        start: '$start',
        linkedUsers: "$linkedUsers",
        users: {$push: {
          id: "$users.id",
          name: "$users.name",
          rounds: "$tags.rounds",
          time: "$tags.time",
          photos: {$push: {
            id: "$photos.id",
            location: "photos.location"
          }}
        }}
    }}
  ])
```

**EDIT 1:**
This is the first error I encounter:

MongoError: The field 'id' must be an accumulator object

I have read up on that, but I don't understand how it all fits together.

**Edit 2:**
I fixed that by wrapping the grouping in a _id: {}

Now I encounter Unrecognized expression '$push'

**Edit 3:**
Running on Atlas, 4.0.4 Enterprise.

Comment: It looks like all good to me. What is the issue?

Comment: The first error I get is: "MongoError: The field 'id' must be an accumulator object"
I have updated my question to include this.

Comment: I fixed that buy wrapping the whole group in a _id: {}

Now I get "MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$push'"

Comment: Use `photos: $photos` only.

Comment: It will be better if you put the version of mongodb you are using

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet thanks. Updated my question now. Running on Atlas, 4.0.4 Enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.group.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "linkedUsers": "$linkedUsers" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$linkedUsers"] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "tags",
        "let": { "userId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$userId", "$$userId"] } } }
        ],
        "as": "tags"
      }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "photos",
        "let": { "userId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$userId", "$$userId"] } } }
        ],
        "as": "photos"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "linkedUsers"
  }}
])
```

**Edit:** Removed blank space in variables

Comment: Excellent. I had started working on some unwind, group solution. But this IMO a way better solution. Worked like a charm as soon as I removed some unintentional blank spaces you had left in the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to create one sample relation dump data

Check working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GnCeZBal608)

Try to group by `_id` and just assign `photos: $photos`.

***Second level `$push` was the issue in your case.***

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$linkedUsers"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "linkedUsers",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "photos",
      localField: "linkedUsers",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "photos"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$photos"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      localField: "linkedUsers",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "tags"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "start": {
        $first: "$start"
      },
      "linkedUsers": {
        $first: "$linkedUsers"
      },
      "users": {
        "$push": {
          "id": "$users._id",
          "name": "$users.name",
          "rounds": "$tags.rounds",
          "time": "$tags.time",
          "photos": "$photos"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As I have created manual data, you may need some key or DB name change to your implementation.

---

> **NOTE:-**
>
> I recommended to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` while using multi level `$unwind`. By which you can have original document present if inner level not found.
>
> ```
> { $unwind: { path: "$tags", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
> ```

---

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This really helped me out in this jungle of questions and answers that are almost the same, but not exactly. Trying to piece together something that works for me.

Comment: I thought I was going to be able to sort the rest myself. But three hours later I'm still not wiser. I have updated your working example to fit my db. And as you see this way if there is more than one photo, you get a user for each photo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/30wCJjcICZg

Please advise.